# How can I merge data with the same key

Tags: javascript, merge

This is the data I have

```
StudentInfo:[
          {
           name:'Rajesh',
              courseDetails:{
               //some info
              }
          },
          {
           name:'Amit',
              courseDetails:{
               //some info
              }
           },
          {
           name:'Rajesh',
              Address:[
               //some info
              ]
          }

]
```

From the above data how do I merge the data with the same key using javascript ?

This is the final result I would like to see

```
StudentInfo:[
          {
           name:'Rajesh',
              courseDetails:{
               //some info
              }
              Address:[
               //some info
              ]
          }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `reduce` along with [`rest` parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).
group by name and then take the values array using `Object.values`

```js
const StudentInfo =[
          {
           name:'Rajesh',
              courseDetails:{
               //some info
              }
          },
          {
           name:'Amit',
              courseDetails:{
               //some info
              }
           },
          {
           name:'Rajesh',
              Address:[
               //some info
              ]
          }

]

const res = Object.values(StudentInfo.reduce((acc,{name,...rest}) => {
  acc[name]??={name}
  acc[name] = {...acc[name],...rest}
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

one liner

```js
const StudentInfo =[          {          name:'Rajesh',              courseDetails:{                     }          },          {           name:'Amit',              courseDetails:{              }           },          {           name:'Rajesh',              Address:[              ]          }]

const res = Object.values(StudentInfo.reduce((acc, { name, ...rest }) => ({...acc,[name]: { ...(acc[name] || {}), name, ...rest }}), {}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @cmgchess-I'm getting reduce is not a function.

Comment: @coder are you calling it on an array. i suspect you are calling it on an object

Comment: @cmgchess- Yes that's correct now it worked but the items in array are showing as [object][object]

Comment: @coder hmm can you not access them

Answer (score 0):

You can just use for of loop with lookup object

```js
const StudentInfo = [{
    name: 'Rajesh',
    courseDetails: {
      //some info
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Amit',
    courseDetails: {
      //some info
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Rajesh',
    Address: [
      //some info
    ]
  }
];


const lookup = {};
const newStudentInfo = [];
for (let [index, student] of StudentInfo.entries()) {
  const key = lookup[student.name];
  if (key >= 0) {
    newStudentInfo[key] = {...newStudentInfo[key], ...student};
  } else {
    lookup[student.name] = index;
    newStudentInfo.push(student);
  }
}

console.log(newStudentInfo);
```